# ASCII Comparisons when Using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: sql-server, collation

I ran the query below to see how strings would compare in SQL Server, since a different query based on comparison of fields with this type of data yielded different results than expected.  I wasn't sure whether the angle bracket would be considered a lower value than a number (based on the ASCII table it would not, but wanted to check).  As a result of the outcome, I've reviewed multiple posts regarding string comparison, collation and expected values and they all seem to reinforce that this should not be working this way.  The collation on the database (as on the field that caused trouble) is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

```
SELECT   ASCII('<') AS [<]
        ,ASCII('0') AS [0]
        ,CASE WHEN '<0.1' < '0.1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST1
        ,CASE WHEN '<' < '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST2
        ,CASE WHEN ASCII('<') < ASCII('0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST3
```

Result:

```
<   0   TEST1   TEST2   TEST3
60  48  1       1       0
```

Any ideas to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The ASCII code and the order that characters are sorted in are not the same. The value returned from `ASCII` is consistent, regardless of the collation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, that helps! As a result of your response, I was trying to find a table or something that defines the sequencing based on collation but apparently this is one of those well-kept secrets.  It's really OK once I know that I can expect the results to be consistent, even if I don't actually know what it's consistent to.